# Why does the embedded image in my email signature not obey its width styling in Outlook on Windows?

Tags: html, outlook, html-email

I've created a custom HTML email signature with an embedded image. The end result in Komodo previewer and Apple Mail client looks like this

[image]

However, once I bring the same HTML code into the Outlook desktop app on a Windows PC the signature renders like this

[image]

It seems like Outlook is ignoring the width styling entirely.

How do I get correct sizing of my embedded image in Outlook?

```
  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"style="background: none;margin: 0;padding: 40px 10px 30px;">
    <tbody>
      <tr style="padding: 0 12px 0 0;">
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;width: 50px;padding: 0 6px 0 0;">
          <a href="http://www.tetonsports.com">
            <img src="https://tetonsports.imagerelay.com/ql/6cde221aa42c4ec8b325b3c0f6235d2e/email-icon-01.png" name="preview-image-url" style="vertical-align: middle;width:69px"/>
          </a>
        </td>
        <td>
          <table>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td style="font-weight: normal;color: #000001;font-size: 14px;font-family: Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif;">TETON Sports</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <div>
                  <td
                     <span style="font-weight: bold;color: #000001;font-size: 14px;font-family: Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif;">Josh Jorgensen</span>
                     <span style="font-weight: bold;color: #FF9E18;font-size: 14px;font-family: Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif;">//</span>
                     <span style="font-style: italic;font-weight: normal;color: #54565A;font-size: 14px;font-family: Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif;">Photographer</span>
                  </td>
                </div>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td valign="top" style="font-style: italic;font-weight: normal;color: #54565A;font-size: 14px;font-family: Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif;">
                  <a style="text-decoration: none;font-style: italic;font-weight: normal;color: #54565A;" href="brandon@tetonsports.com">josh@tetonsports.com</a>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using the `width` HTML attribute of the `<img>` tag like this: `width="69"`?

Here's the whole tag:

```
<img src="https://tetonsports.imagerelay.com/ql/6cde221aa42c4ec8b325b3c0f6235d2e/email-icon-01.png" name="preview-image-url" style="vertical-align: middle;" width="69"/>
```

Comment: ^this. Outlook ignores width in a style tag, only `width` tag is valid.